# Drupal Front Page "404 Page Not Found"

Tags: caching, drupal, drupal-8, drupal-9

I have a website "https://www.example.com" which is suddenly showing 404 Page Not Found.

Header Footer is coming but in the body part its showing nothing but appearing a Page Not Found text.

But if I access "https://www.example.com/home" it's working fine.

Even all inner pages are working too except the front page.

I tried changing Default Front Page in Configuration > Basic Site Settings but nothing helped at all.

Also cleared cache multiple times.

Please help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's seems that's your problem from your apache configuration (or nginx).
Maybe this topic may help you : https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/installing-drupal/2020-05-14/can-access-the-homepage-but-everything-else-gives-404

Other documentation :

- Clean URLs not working? Check your .htaccess file! : https://www.drupal.org/node/256410
- Configure Apache for Drupal : https://www.drupal.org/node/2461583
- Tips on configuring .htaccess for Drupal 8 : https://www.zyxware.com/articles/4544/drupal-tips-on-configuring-htaccess-for-drupal-8

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in settings.php file. The base url of the microsite settings was not mentioned correctly, also the public url was wrong.

```
$config['micro_site.settings']['base_url'] = 'MY_HOSTNAME';
$config['micro_site.settings']['base_scheme'] = 'HTTP OR HTTPS';
$config['micro_site.settings']['public_url'] = 'MY_HOSTNAME';
```